# append named vector in R

Tags: r

In R how to create and append 'named' vector. My current approach is to create separate names vector and assign names later.

```
v = c()
vName = c()
for (i in 1:5) {
  # do something complicated and store output
  k = i*i ## or get output from any other function 
  v = c(v,k)
  vName = c(vName, k)
}
names(v) = vName
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: One side point is that it is always a bad idea to iteratively append to a vector (or data.frame). When possible, pre-allocate the vector using something like numeric(vectorLength). even if you don't know the exact size, overshooting it will still be better than appending.

Comment: @jogo The aim is not to simply create a named vector but to append it with some output (did some edit in the example).

Comment: @lmo Can you please provide an example ?

Comment: You can try to add `names(v) <- c(names(v)[1:(i-1)],k)` in the loop.

Comment: @d.putto See my answer.

Comment: Why the hell question is downvoted not even telling what is wrong ?

Comment: @d.putto Why are you appending `k` to both: `v` and `vName`? Why do you not assign the names after the loop: `for (..) { .. }; names(v) <- v` ?

Comment: @jogo please read my edit and comment in the code.

Comment: @d.putto I read your edited question, but I could't find a answer to my questions. I don't understand: if the calculation of `k` is complex then speeding up the appending of the elements to `v` (and to `vName`) doesn't much matter. Otherwise (if the calculation of `k` is cheap) the suggestions in my comments will give easier (and faster) code.

Answer (score 5):

In some simple situations, you can use `setNames`:

```
setNames(1:5, letters[1:5])
```

but applying names outside of the loop is a good way to go. If you pre-allocate the vector, you can add the names within the loop:

```
# pre-allocate vectors of known size (length of for loop)
v=numeric(5)
vName = character(5)
for (i in 1:5) {
  # do something complicated and store output
  k = i*i ## or get output from any other function
  kName = <something related to k>

  v[i] = k
  vName[i] = kName
}
```

Pre-allocating the vectors, sets up a fixed spot in memory that get filled in the loop. If you repeatedly append to them, R has to make copies of the vectors in every iteration.

Comment: plus 1 for the hint with the pre-allocation.

Answer (score 1):

Another way you could append the name inside the loop is to use names():

```
# Create empty vector of known size
v <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = 5)
# Fill the named vector with the loop
for (i in 1:5) {
    k <- i*i 
    kName <- paste0("name", i) # generates "name1", "name2", etc
    v[i] <- k # adds element to vector
    names(v)[i] <- kName # adds name to the current element 
}
```